# Generate entity with PHPCR

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf

Earlier, I used pure essence created a symfony that `app/console doctrine: generate: entites`, but at the moment, it is necessary to deal with the Symfony CMF. Could you write commands that you need to do in order to register the entity and generate getters and setters, which can juzat in the controller. For example, I need to create a username field, a password. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

For Doctrine PHPCR-ODM, the generator command has not yet been contributed by anybody. There is a discussion in the [github tracker](https://github.com/doctrine/phpcr-odm/issues/361) and it would be great if somebody ports that code from doctrine ORM or writes a generic generator in the process.

Luckily, an IDE can also generate getters and setters, and the mapping is not that complicated to write. You find the documentation in the [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-phpcr-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).